# MSAL Interceptor: How to retrieve token claims right after login before initializing components?

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I have an Angular app authenticating against Azure AD. I get a bearer token that is being used to authenticate and authorize API calls. That works fine.

However, I need to access the group and role claims in the token BEFORE initializing any components. I manage to get these claims, but obviously it is too late. I save the token and its claims, respectively, to localStorage but I need to reload the page before they are being read in time.

I am using the MSALInterceptor with InteractionType.Redirect. The following code is in my app.component.ts to retrieve the token claims:

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$
      .pipe(
        filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.HandleRedirect), // status === InteractionStatus.None || 
        takeUntil(this._destroying$)
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.checkAndSetActiveAccount();
        console.log(this.msalService.instance.getActiveAccount());
      })
  }
```

The problem is that right after login `this.msalService.instance.getActiveAccount()` returns `null`. That means that after successfully authenticating I need to reload the page, then it will return the token including the claims. So obviously I am doing it the wrong way, I can't figure out when, where and how I am supposed to retrieve the token from MSAL. I also tried putting the same code in another component, but the result is the same.

Any suggestions are more than welcome!

This is the relevant parts of my app.module.ts in case it matters:

```js
export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: environment.clientID, 
      authority: environment.authority, 
      redirectUri: environment.redirectUri,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: '/'
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
    },
    system: {
      loggerOptions: {
        loggerCallback,
        logLevel: LogLevel.Info,
        piiLoggingEnabled: false
      }
    }
  }
  );
}

export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
  let protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>([
    [environment.apiUrl, [environment.apiScope]],
    ['/', [environment.apiScope]],
  ]);

  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    protectedResourceMap
  };
}

export function MSALGuardConfigFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {
  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    authRequest: {
      scopes: [environment.apiScope]
    },
    loginFailedRoute: '/login-failed'
  };
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: tokenGetter
      }
    }),
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    OrderModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: PanelComponent, canActivate: [MsalGuard], pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]),
    MsalModule
      .forRoot(new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: environment.clientID,
        authority: environment.authority,
        redirectUri: environment.redirectUri
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
      }
    }), MSALGuardConfigFactory(), MSALInterceptorConfigFactory())
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
      useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory
    },
    MsalService,
    MsalGuard,
    MsalBroadcastService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent]
})
```